# SAML support in Microsoft Teams Apps

Tags: azure, botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-identity-platform

After going through the documentation related to Single Sign on and Teams Authentication for the Bot framework, we had a question regarding the SAML support for authentication. Is SAML supported or does the Teams App authentication support only the Oauth flow.

Here are the documentation I have referred to-

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso-bots
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/auth-flow-bot
3. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-flow-tab

Answer (score 0):

Currently Teams App authentication supports Oauth flow and SAML support is not there.

Comment: To achieve SAML  based authentication -:
Can we create an enterprise application that uses SAML-based authentication and link that application id with team app webApplicationInfo id? 
@Meghana-MSFT

Comment: @user3755154 - No, WebApplicationInfo uses AAD ID which supports Oauth only.